# iOS - initWithContentsOfURL downloading old version of file

Tags: ios, iphone, initwithcontentsofurl

My app downloads text files from a server in order to determine the content of the files. There's one problem, I am changing the files on the server, editing their content, but when the app downloads them the files have no changed. Loading the files up in a browser shows that the changes did take effect. Somehow the app is accessing an older version of the file that shouldn't exist. Here's my code:

```
 -(NSArray *)writeFile:(NSString *)section :(NSString *)item{
      NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/%@/%@.txt", section, item];
    fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                     withString:@"%20"];
    NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: fileName] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSLog(@"Read from file: %@", fileName);
    NSLog(@"Content: %@", data);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt", item]];
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];

    NSArray *  arrayData = [content componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
             [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n\n"]
             ];
    return arrayData;


}
```

There's one file that is only a single character, a number, and THAT file downloads correctly each time. The rest of the files are larger with multiple lines. When I move the files to a different server they will download the correct version of the files, but if I make changes again and try to redownload from the new source, the changes are not reflected in the download (but still on the server).

I am so confused, I can't see any reason that it would do this, unless it's saving some form of a cookie. Ideas?

Comment: It sounds like a cache problem. Instead of using initWithContentsOfURL, try using NSURLConnection and use requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval: so you can tell the download not use cached content.

Comment: I figured it out, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was phone's fault. I was using my Note 3 as a wireless hotspot because the normal wifi connection's range is 20 feet away from where I sit. Once I hooked up to a traditional wifi, it worked just fine.